# Use java lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm beginning with Java 8 and I was wondering if I can convert a loop with a try-catch clause, into a lambda function?
Below is the method code I would like to convert into:

```
for (File f: files) { 
    JSONOject obj; 
    try (FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("path.csv")) {
        obj= (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileWriter(f)); 
        readOBJ(valueType,results,obj); 
        results.put(day, new JobClass(day,work, time,description)); 
        Date d= results.keySet();
        Calendar c= Calendar.getinstance(); 
        c.setTime(d); 
        Map<Date, JobClass> daysList= new HashMap<>(); 
        j.insertDaysList(results,c,fw,daysList);
        results.putAll(daysList); 
        j.resSort(results,resDayList); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.printStacktrace();
       }
} 
return resDaysList;
```

Comment: I don’t know what parser you are using, but passing a *writer* to a parser looks very unusual… The line `Date d= results.keySet();` doesn’t look very convincing either. And it’s completely unclear where the result `resDaysList`, you are returning, does come from. In other words, you spit out some non-working code and ask us for converting it to a lambda function. First, we are not a code rewriting service, second, there is no benefit in converting this into a lambda function. Trying to turn it into correct code could pay off more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the `files` iteration you want to convert to a `Stream`, that can easily be done.  At the moment, your loop contents don't even throw uncaught exceptions, so there's no difficulty here (though I would suggest refactoring it into its own method first).

Answer (score 0):

As lambda expressions in Java are just a means to conveniently provide implementations of single-abstract-method (SAM) interfaces as anonymous objects and the standard `Stream` interface offers the `forEach()` method for internal iteration, you can encapsulate pretty much everything you want to within your expression.

`forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)` expects you to provide it with an object of the `Consumer` interface, which need only have one method implementation consuming an object of any kind and returning no value.

So you simply put the code within your loop into the expression (or, as already proposed, transfer it into it's own method first) and you're done. The only thing you'll need to think about is how to treat your `return` statement, as it's not possible to return values from within the `forEach()` method (due to it being a so called "terminal" method of return type `void`). But you'll be able to pass your list into the lambda expression, modify your values in any way you see fit and keep working with it after the lambda is done, without any problem.

The try-catch-block does not affect the lambda expression itself. After all, the following two segments of code are equivalent:

```
List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("example", "of", "lambda", "code");

// lambda style
someList.stream().forEach( item -> {
  try {
    System.out.println(item.toString());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
});

// anonymous object style
someList.stream().forEach(new Consumer<String>() {

  @Override
  public void accept(String s) {
    try {
      System.out.println(item.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: So in this case my list should be the list of files (files) and the object consumer the file (f) ?

Comment: Yes, maybe it's  better passing the code into it's own method.